# The data in my custom settings page can't be saved

Tags: php, database, wordpress

### The data can not be saved

I am trying to make settings pages for each custom post type so that I can insert specified posts to archive pages of those post types.

I made this settings page using Wordpress Settings API.

But even after I input some values and clicked the save button.

[image]

The data can not be saved on DB and no data are displayed in these forms after refreshing the page.

I also confirmed the database has not created a record of the data. 'post_type_top' should be the option_name in DB.

[image]

Here is my class file to implement this settings page.

Does anyone figure out what kind of error this has?

I am temporarily commented out some sanitization process in my code.

```
<?php

class CreateSettingsPage
{
    private $options;
    private $post_type;
    private $settings = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_settings_page'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'settings_page_init'));
        $this->post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
        $this->settings = array(
            'page' => 'post-type-settings-admin',
            'page_title' => __('Post Type Settings', 'tcd-w'),
            'page_slug' => 'post_type_top',
            'option_name' => 'post_type_top',
            'option_group' => 'post_type_top_option_group',
            'sections' => array(
                array(
                    'id_prefix' => 'post_type_settings',
                    'section_title' => __('Add Links to Post Type Top', 'tcd-w'),
                    'section_info' => __('Please input category page slug and post ids which are added to the post type top page', 'tcd-w'),
                    'fields' => array(
                        array(
                            'field_id' => 'input_category_slug',
                            'field_title' => 'input_category_slug',
                            'type' => 'input',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'field_id' => 'input_post_ids',
                            'field_title' => 'input_post_ids',
                            'type' => 'input',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function add_settings_page()
    {

        //put a menu within all custom types if apply
        $post_types = get_post_types();
        foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

            //check if there are any taxonomy for this post type
            $post_type_taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);

            foreach ($post_type_taxonomies as $key => $taxonomy_name) {
                $taxonomy_info = get_taxonomy($taxonomy_name);
                if (empty($taxonomy_info->hierarchical) ||  $taxonomy_info->hierarchical !== TRUE)
                    unset($post_type_taxonomies[$key]);
            }

            if (count($post_type_taxonomies) == 0)
                continue;

            if ($post_type == 'post') {
                add_submenu_page('edit.php', $this->settings['page_title'], $this->settings['page_title'], 'manage_options',  $this->settings['page_slug'] . '_' . $post_type, array($this, 'create_admin_page'));
            } elseif ($post_type == 'attachment') {
                add_submenu_page('upload.php', $this->settings['page_title'], $this->settings['page_title'], 'manage_options', $this->settings['page_slug'] . '_' . $post_type, array($this, 'create_admin_page'));
            } else {
                add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type, $this->settings['page_title'], $this->settings['page_title'], 'manage_options', $this->settings['page_slug'] . '_' . $post_type, array($this, 'create_admin_page'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        $this->options = get_option($this->settings['option_name']); ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php echo $this->settings['page_title']; ?></h2>
            <p></p>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">

                <?php
                settings_fields($this->settings['option_group']);
                do_settings_sections($this->settings['page']);
                submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php }

    public function settings_page_init()
    {

        register_setting(
            $this->settings['option_group'], // option_group
            $this->settings['sections']['option_name'],
            array($this, 'sanitize') // sanitize_callback
        );

        foreach ($this->settings['sections'] as $section) {
            add_settings_section(
                $section['id_prefix'] . '_section', // id
                $section['section_title'], // title
                array($this, 'section_info'), // callback
                $this->settings['page'] // page
            );

            foreach ($section['fields'] as $field) {
                add_settings_field(
                    $field['field_id'] . '_' . $this->post_type, // id
                    $field['field_title'], // title
                    array($this, $field['type']), // callback
                    $this->settings['page'], // page
                    $section['id_prefix'] . '_section', // section
                    $field
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public function sanitize($input)
    {

        return $input;

        // $sanitary_values = array();
        // if (isset($input['custom_banner_url_0'])) {
        //     $sanitary_values['custom_banner_url_0'] = sanitize_text_field($input['custom_banner_url_0']);
        // }

        // if (isset($input['custom_banner_img_src_1'])) {
        //     $sanitary_values['custom_banner_img_src_1'] = esc_textarea($input['custom_banner_img_src_1']);
        // }

        // return $sanitary_values;
    }

    public function section_info()
    {
        echo $section['section_info'];
    }

    public function input($field)
    {
        printf(
            '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="%s[%s]" id="%s" value="%s">',
            $this->settings['option_name'],
            $field['field_id'] . '_' . $this->post_type,
            $field['field_id'] . '_' . $this->post_type,
            isset($this->options[$field['field_id'] . '_' . $this->post_type]) ? esc_attr($this->options[$field['field_id'] . '_' . $this->post_type]) : ''
        );
    }

    public function textarea($field)
    {
        printf(
            '<textarea class="large-text" rows="5" name="%s[%s]" id="%s">%s</textarea>',
            $this->settings['option_name'],
            $field['field_id'],
            $field['field_id'],
            isset($this->options[$field['field_id']]) ? esc_attr($this->options[$field['field_id']]) : ''
        );
    }
}
if (is_admin()) $post_type_settings = new CreateSettingsPage();
```